# My Nokia Lumia cannot stay on the internet for a long time

Tags: lumia-925

Whenever I go on to the internet I stay on for about 10 minutes and then it kicks me off it without any warning. My WiFi never cuts out, so I know its not that. Can you help me please. The phone is a Nokia Lumia 925.

Comment: Are you talking about using your mobile data connection? What do you mean when you say "it kicks me off"? Do you get an error message? What version of Windows or Windows Phone is your phone running?